# Extract text between two words, multi-line with validation

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex to identify text between two words over multiline, "TYPE" and "ENDS".

```
TYPE

     words words words

ENDS
```

However, if the contents contain a specific words, like BODY this should not be a valid match.
This is invalid, because between TYPE, and ENDS we have BODY

```
TYPE

     words words words

     BODY <== BAD

     words words words

ENDS
```

However, this is valid, and therefore "words words words" is the desired output:

```
TYPE

     words words words

ENDS

BODY

     more more more

ENDS
```

The best I have so far is:

```
(\btype\b((?!.[\s\S]*\bbody\b).*)\bends\b)
```

Comment: You forgot to post the code you're having issues with. Please read [ask], [edit] and create a  [mcve]. Also, it's not very clear what is the desired output.

Comment: Hi Roko :( the best I have so far is:

(\btype\b((?!.[\s\S]*\bbody\b).*)\bends\b).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a Negative Assertion (Lookahead or Lookback). [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Here's an example: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DZuIyP/1/)

```
TYPE\n(((?!BODY).)*)\nENDS
```

The `(?!BODY)` matches if the content does not match `BODY`.
`((?!BODY).)*` matches `.*`, and every character does not have a `BODY` before it.
Please note that the regex enables SingleLine, which `.` can also match line break, it does not conflict with MultiLine.

If you do not want to use the single-line mode and word boundaries, try this one: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DZuIyP/5/)

```
\bTYPE\b\s*(((?!\bBODY\b)(.|\s))*?)\s*\sENDS\s
```

Basically the same but just manually match `\s`, and with `\b` around words.

Edit:
The old regex is

- `\bTYPE\b\s*`
- `(` ... `)`

  - `(` ... `)*?`

    - `(?!\bBODY\b)(.|\s)`
- `\s*\sENDS\s`

In order to allow quoted version, you can add it inside

- `\bTYPE\b\s*`
- `(` ... `)`

  - `(` ... `)*?`

    - `(?!\bBODY\b)(.|\s)` or `(?<=")(?=BODY").`

      - The first one disallow the combination of (`.` then `BODY`)
      - The second one allow the combination of (`"` then `BODY"`), there's no `.`.
      - The `.` in the second matches `B` in `"BODY"`, so you can replace it with `B`.
- `\s*\sENDS\s`

Result: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DZuIyP/6)

Comment: Any suggestion on how the body in speech marks can be accepted?

TYPE

     words "body" words

ENDS

Comment: @Matt Answer updated for `"BODY"`. [Sample](https://regex101.com/r/DZuIyP/6), you can delete any of the quotes, and it won't match.